# HttpUtility.UrlEncode adding zero width space BOM

Tags: c#, encoding

```
string x = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( "<div>U N I.</div>\r\n​ABC");
```

Output : x = "%3cdiv%3eU+N+I.%3c%2fdiv%3e%0d%0a%e2%80%8bABC"

As you can see it is adding the Zero Width Space %e2%80%8b.

Is there a way we can encode the string without adding the byte order mark????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string already contains this zero-width space. C# allows Unicode characters in many places. Confirm that by deleting ">\r\nA" in a text editor and typing it anew.

Comment: Yes you are right .. Deleting ">\r\nA" and encoding it doesn't produce this zero width space ..

Comment: But is it possible to not encode the zero-width-space?

Comment: Yes - remove it from the source string.

Comment: Won't that cause output to lose %0d%0a?? I require that \r\n part too

Comment: Well, don't remove the other spaces if you want to keep them. `str.Replace("\x200B", "")`. I hope I got that Unicode escape code right.